# Is it necessary to open all used ports when using one Node.JS application to route from port 80 to apps on different ones?

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, ubuntu-12.04, portforwarding

I'm working with an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64 Bit server there I have used the following commands to send all http request on port 80 to port 8080

Commands:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward #returns 1
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

From there I wanted to proxy the requests based on (sub)domain to some other ports (i.e. 9000, 3000, 9615) using [http-master](https://github.com/CodeCharmLtd/http-master). I'm having some problems getting this done and had it right once on a VPS on amazon aws where those ports where opened.

So what I'm asking is if it's necessary to open every port and how I can do that on the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research and experimentation I concluded that it's only necessary to open the port that we use as entry points. If we then route it with a proxy or even with NAT configuration to another PORT, the latter will be used only to "listen".